# Datepicker VueJS, correct visualize but not sending in the same format

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

We are using datepicker plugin but we saw that it visualizes in the correct date format, but it is send to the server/DB in the default format of datepicker.

```
<datepicker
  v-model="model.date"
  placeholder="Choose date"
  :format="DatePickerFormat"
  id="date"
  name="date">
</datepicker>

<script>
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'

export default {
  components: {
     Datepicker
  }
data() {
    return {
       DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
       model: {
        date: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In the input field it visualizes correct, but when the data is send by clicking the button Save, format is `date: "2018-06-27T10:34:09.502Z"` How can I standardize the both formats to be in "DD/MM/YYYY"?

Answer (score 2):

Add this `valueType="format"` attribute to your `<date-picker>` component.

So, the entire component will be like

```
<date-picker v-model="delivery_date" lang="en" type="date" valueType="format" :format="'YYYY-MM-DD'"></date-picker>
```

Now the returning value will be like `2020-09-06`. You can set other **valueTypes** as well.

Checkout this page:
https://mengxiong10.github.io/vue2-datepicker/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `DatePickerFormat` inside `data` option, you defined it as a [custom property.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options)

To access it you should use `$opptions.DatePickerFormat`.

So change `:format="DatePickerFormat"` to

```
:format="$options.DatePickerFormat"
```

Or else define it in the `data` option as

```
data() {
    return {
       model: {
        date: ''
      },
      DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Done, however it still sends the format in "date" : "2018-06-27T11:02:52.531Z"

Comment: I need to change the default format in which is sent.

Comment: Still having problem with parsing the date in right format. When I choose the date in dropdown menu it shows in "dd/mm/yyyy", but when it's send it's in format "2018-06-29T07:51:58.795Z". It needs to be in the format "dd/mm/yyyy".

Comment: @Decrux I have tried it out in a fiddle and get the same output as you mention i.e` "2018-06-29T07:51:58.795Z"`.

Comment: Is there a solution for this? Because I am looking everywhere but without success.

Comment: @Decrux try raising  an issue on the github repo

Comment: I raised an issue. Meanwhile, could recommend another datepicker plugin or some workaround?

Comment: You can create your own. I created one using flatpickr in my [project](https://github.com/rvamsikrishna/vue-world/blob/master/src/components/DateTimeInput.vue). You can have a look  at it.. Its not welll commented

Answer (score 0):

Please use :value instead of v-model. It works for me!!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).